# Find three subspaces $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ of $k [X]$ such that $k[X]\cong W_1\oplus W_2\oplus W_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I am trying to find three non-trivial subspaces of all polynomials, there are infinite subspaces of the space of all polynomials? I could fix a natural $n$ and say that the polynomials of degree less than $n$ are a subspace, those of degree equal to n other and those of degree greater than $n$ another and in this case could not arm the direct sum with those three subspaces?

Comment: Polynomials of degree $\geq n$ are not a subspace. Consider $x^3+x^2,$ and $x^3$ are both degree 3, but their difference  is degree 2, so this set is not closed under differences, and therefore not a subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$k\bigl[X^3\bigr]$ could be one of them. Can you proceed from there?

Comment: I was thinking about this when you wrote it down. This is a solid approach :D

Comment: The harder point was find only a hint, not the solution!

Comment: Could $k[X^2], k[X^3]$ and $k[X^4]$ then serve?

Comment: No, because you can't obtain $X$ with these subspaces. Further, the pairwise intersections are not $\{0\}$. Just think of $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @user402543, try to think about the possible degrees in $k[X^3],$ and then ask yourself which ones are missing, and how to  get them.

Comment: $k[X^3]$ denotes the polynomials of degree 3 or the polynomials of degree of multiple of 3?

Comment: Or, said otherwise, classify all terms $c_kX^k$  which make up a polynomial according to the value of $k\bmod3$.

Comment: @Bernard The subspaces of a field K are only K and (0)?

Comment: Yes, for dimensions reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A basis of $k[X]$ is $1, X, X^2, X^3, \dots$. The only thing you have to do is divide the basis elements in three groups, so for instance
$$\begin{align*}
W_1 &= \text{span}(1) = k \\
W_2 & = \text{span}(X) = k \cdot X \\
W_3 & = \text{span}(X^2, X^3, \dots) = X^2 \cdot k[X]\\
\end{align*}
$$
would work.